MudBlazor DatePicker 'Not a valid date time' error message
I would like to change the 'Not a valid date time' error message of MudDatePicker to my own custom message, but I do not know how. I tried using FluentValidation, but it is not being called. I suspect this is due to the 'Required' constraint on the control. I also tried using the Error attribute, but it doesn't work because the original message is displayed.
And I tried to use the Error attribute, but it doesn't work.
<MudDatePicker ReadOnly="@(!_editCustomerInProgress)" Label="Birth date" Clearable="true" @bind-Date="CustomerDto.BirthDate"
   DateFormat="yyyy.MM.dd" Placeholder="yyyy.mm.dd" Editable=true Mask="@(new DateMask("yyyy.MM.dd"))"
   Required="@_editCustomerInProgress" RequiredError="It is required" For="@(() => CustomerDto.BirthDate)" 
   **Error=@(!DateTime.TryParse(CustomerDto.BirthDate.ToString(), out _)) ErrorText="It is not a valid birth date."** />

UPDATE
I would like to change or remove this message:


The Not a valid date time error should only be shown if the input date cannot be successfully converted to a DateTime. It should no be related to the validation that you are performing

Hi Anu6is,My problem is that when I start typing the date, the control shows this message and I cannot change it.

can you reproduce using https://try.mudblazor.com/

When you start to type the date, the error message is displayed. I cannot decide whether it is a Chrome behavior or something else. https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/camoYJdbmwOGuOEq

This looks like an issue with MudBlazor when using masks in the date picker, not sure you can get around it yourself. Maybe submit a issue on their GitHub
